Solidity gaslimit for chaining call?
i have the following:
contract Example {
    function A() external {
        (bool success,) = address(this).call{gas: 1_000_000}(abi.encodeWithSelector(this.B.selector));
        console.log("A", success);
    }

    function B() external {
        console.log("i have", gasleft());
        (bool success,) = address(this).call{gas: 10_000_000}(abi.encodeWithSelector(this.useInfiniteGas.selector));
        console.log("B", success);
        console.log("ok", gasleft());
    }

    function useInfiniteGas() external view {
        console.log("i am given", gasleft());
        while (true) {}
    }
}

after calling A(), i would expect
  i have 1M
  i am given 10M
  [the first call runs out of 1M gas before the second one uses 10M]
  A false

but instead i get
  i have 999817
  i am given 980422
  B false
  ok 14714
  A true

it seems like despite me setting 10M gas for B, it actually only got 980422, which has enough left (14714) to let A succeed. How does this work exactly?
same behavior occurs with delegatecall. if i set the 10M to anything above 980422 or remove it, same behavior. but if i set the 10M to anything below 980422, it now regains control of its gas limit.

Which tool are you using to compile this code ?

i am using foundry

EIP-150 allows you to only send G - Math.floor(G/64) when making an call or delegatecall. This is implemented so that you will at least have Math.floor(G/64) remaining to complete the rest of your operations after call or delegatecall is complete.
Take the example of call to useInfiniteGas(). The gasleft() was 999817 when you printed it in function B()   .
G- Math.floor(G/64) with G as 999817 gives 984195 gas . But your abi.encodeWithSelector() is also consuming some gas which will reduce G so the actual amount of gas you are allowed to consume on useInfiniteGas() will be (984194-g) - Math.floor((984194-g)/64) which should come out to 980422. where g is gas consumed for the encodeWithSelector operation .
Another important thing to note is that the call doesn't revert even when you provided 10 million gas, it just takes the capped value and passes it as gas

ok got it! so A just so happens to succeed. but if i add something like x++; to the end of function B, A now runs out of gas and fails.

@Junion The gas left at end of function B() is 14714 . If X is a state variable whose initial value was 0 than it will take 22100 gas just to update it (the cost of sstore) . That's why it's failing
The rules for gas calculation for sstore -
static_gas = 0

if value == current_value
    base_dynamic_gas = 100
else if current_value == original_value
    if original_value == 0
        base_dynamic_gas = 20000
    else
        base_dynamic_gas = 2900
else
    base_dynamic_gas = 100

2100 is added  if the slot is cold.
